# How to use elasticsearch geo query to get documents with distance greater than x kilometres

Tags: elasticsearch

Hey I am working on an application where I need to display places from the provided latitude longitude based on distance filter . I am serving data from elastic search . I can easily serve data using geo_distance query for finding documents with geo-points within the specified distance of a central point. But I am unable to search data for greater than x kilometres

Elastic search version - 6.6

Mapping -

```
{
  "mappings": {
  "_doc": {
   "properties": {
     "location": {
       "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

To get places less than x kilometres I use this query

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool" : {
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "15km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat"  : 40.1111,
                    "lon"  : 40.1111 
                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What query to use to get results greater than x km , does geo filter provide any query parameter to get data greater than x distance ?
Can I use filter in combination with must_not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to replace `filter` by `must_not` and that will achieve what you need:

```
{
 "query": {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "15km",
                "location" : {
                    "lat"  : 40.1111,
                    "lon"  : 40.1111 
                }
             }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solving I thought geoDistance can only be used with filter query , cleared that doubt also